# How to add the same character repeatedly to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to trigger an API which needed me to pass 10 character of string. Say I have a parameter

```
string foo = "foo";
```

But to sent to this API, instead of sending `"foo"`, I need to sent `"foo          "` instead.

Does .net have a string function to make this task easier?

Any c# or vb.net code is acceptable.

Comment: It seems weird that an API you need to use requires a fixed length string parameter.  It seems the API is not .NET.  You may need to clarify from the API docs what type of strings are they accepting.  Encoding, size (wide), null-terminated, etc are some of the factors when passing strings from system to system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`String.PadRight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string paddedFoo = foo.PadRight(10);
```